# Can I show Ubuntu OS in a laptop in a short movie or do I need any kind of rights?

Tags: legal

I'm making a short movie and I've this doubt... Can I show one man using Ubuntu without asking any kind of permissions? I don't know if it's legal to use Ubuntu UI or if there is any kind of rights management in this operating system.

I'm sorry if this is not the right place to post this.

Comment: Yes it is perfectly legal. This would probably even be the case for non-free operating systems.

Comment: I don't see why it would not be legal _but_ if your legal department wants to receive a confirmation, you'd have to contact Canonical, Inc. directly

Comment: In what context is Ubuntu shown? E. g., normal every day computer use should be fine but if you publish a movie about a criminal buying *illegal* drugs and firearms on the internet with a *computer running Ubuntu* and *prominently visible names or logos* from Ubuntu or Canonical, the latter might perceive that as a *negative impact for the reputation* of at least one of their trade marks.